# Kodi constantly crashing when scraping TV

Tags: ubuntu, crash, kodi

I have a Kodi 16.1 installation on a Ubuntu 16 VM and it has stopped working. It constantly crashes when it is scraping TV.

I have removed `~/.kodi` and it works normally, but as soon as I added back my `advancedsettings.xml` and pointed it to my TV directory it crashed.

Oddly, it was able to scrape my Movie library just fine, only TV causes an issue.

Here is some of the log, it was 7MB log so I trimmed some stuff. Any ideas what could be the issue?

```
############## Kodi CRASH LOG ###############



################ SYSTEM INFO ################

 Date: Sat Aug  3 04:38:57 PDT 2019

 Kodi Options: 

 Arch: x86_64

 Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016

 Release: Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

############## END SYSTEM INFO ##############



############### STACK TRACE #################

=====>  Core file: /home/sysadmin/core (2019-08-03 04:38:57.897997384 -0700)

        =========================================

[New LWP 2892]

[New LWP 2857]

[New LWP 2859]

[New LWP 2860]

[New LWP 2862]

[New LWP 2866]

[New LWP 2867]

[New LWP 2868]

[New LWP 2869]

[New LWP 2871]

[New LWP 2873]

[New LWP 2875]

[New LWP 2876]

[New LWP 2877]

[New LWP 2878]

[New LWP 2879]

[New LWP 2880]

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Core was generated by `/usr/lib/kodi/kodi.bin'.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

#0  0x00007f129c372bbc in _int_malloc (av=av@entry=0x7f1254000020, bytes=bytes@entry=79) at malloc.c:3353

[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f1286542700 (LWP 2892))]



Thread 17 (Thread 0x7f124dffb700 (LWP 2880)):

#0  0x00007f129c3ee5d3 in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84

#1  0x0000000001044936 in JSONRPC::CTCPServer::Process() ()

#2  0x0000000001d2ac6f in CThread::Action() ()

#3  0x0000000001d2af2f in CThread::staticThread(void*) ()

#4  0x00007f12a26866ba in start_thread (arg=0x7f124dffb700) at pthread_create.c:333

#5  0x00007f129c3f841d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109



Thread 16 (Thread 0x7f124e7fc700 (LWP 2879)):

#0  0x00007f129c3ee5d3 in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84

#1  0x00000000010429bc in SOCKETS::CSocketListener::Listen(int) ()

#2  0x000000000103689e in EVENTSERVER::CEventServer::Run() ()

#3  0x0000000001036b48 in EVENTSERVER::CEventServer::Process() ()

#4  0x0000000001d2ac6f in CThread::Action() ()

#5  0x0000000001d2af2f in CThread::staticThread(void*) ()

#6  0x00007f12a26866ba in start_thread (arg=0x7f124e7fc700) at pthread_create.c:333

#7  0x00007f129c3f841d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109
```

Update: Looks like the issue is related to TVDB.com API Changes and AddOn Update. Going to post this thread regardless and update when fix is live, but nothing is wrong with my installation it appears.

See --> https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=345935

Comment: Good thing I totally wiped my VM and started fresh and re-installed the os and on and on... Finally found that thread, at least I know the issue is not on my end now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this issue has been fixed all you need to do is update the TVDB addon. You may have trouble if your Kodi instance keeps crashing while updating on start. My fix was the following:

- Disable Networking
- Start Kodi
- Disable Auto-Update on Start
- Close Kodi
- Enable Networking
- Update Add-On
- Re-Enable Auto-Update on Start